# Django Email - [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, django

I am looking to allow the user to upload and send a document via email from my django app. When I go to send the email I get the error "[Errno 2] No such file or directory:".

I have tried using a relative path as well as specifying the path but I get the same error either way. I can see that the file is being successfully loaded to that location...so I feel I must be missing something obvious here. Here is my view:

```
def email(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = EmailForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
          # post.published_date = timezone.now()
            post.save()
            email = request.POST.get('email')
            subject = request.POST.get('subject')
            message = request.POST.get('message')
            document = request.FILES.get('document')
            email_from = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
            recipient_list = [email]
            email = EmailMessage(subject,message,email_from,recipient_list)
            base_dir = 'media'
            email.attach_file('Desktop/WBU2/Poseidon/media/media/'+str(document))
            #also tried email.attach_file('/media/'+str(document))
            email.send()
    else:
        form = EmailForm()
        return render(request, 'docemail.html', {'form': form})
```

models.py

```
class Mails(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    message = models.CharField(max_length=20000)
    document = models.FileField(upload_to='media')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use absolute path with "/" in the beginning of the line.
For example:

```
path = '/Users/xxx/Desktop/WBU2/Poseidon/media/media/'+str(document)
```

Comment: ...except putting an absolute path into your code doesn't make a lot of sense. It couples the code to the current machine. OP, why are you trying to open a file from some arbitrary path on your filesystem in the first place?

Comment: I'm not trying to use an absolute path necessarily...I am trying to get the app to send an email with an attachment.  So when the user choose their file, it uploads to the /media folder, and then from there that file is attached to the email.  But when I use 'media' that does not work.

Comment: and thank you for the reply but still no luck even defining the absolute path.

Comment: Make print(path) in you code before email.send() and check existence file at this path